# Get error "system.xml.xmldictionaryreader does not contain a definition for CreateTextReader "

Tags: windows-phone-7

I got the error system.xml.xmldictionaryreader does not contain a definition for 'CreateTextReader' on the VS2010 Express for Windows phone. The code is used for webpage and it works, then I copied into my phone application.  I had added "System.Runtime.Serialization" and "using System.xml" as reference. Would someone show me how to solve this problem. Thanks.

There are the class as using:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;
using System.Text;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;

   public static T Deserializer<T>(Stream s)
    {
        //Get results   
        var ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
        var reader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(s,
            new System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas());
        ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
        var deserializedItem = (T)ser.ReadObject(reader, true);
        reader.Close();
        return deserializedItem;
    }
    #endregion
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That overload is not [supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa346766) on the phone.

Read the stream in a byte[] array first and then feed it the [CreateBinaryReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa346742) overload